# PHP Read CSV and filter by date

Tags: php

I have the following CSV

```
Date,Event,Description
24/01/2010,Football,Football practice for all Years.
24/01/2010,Cricket,Cricket Practice for all Years.
25/01/2010,Piano Lessons,Paino lessons for Year 10.
```

`Date, Event and Description` are the headers that I want to filter by.

I'm getting todays date and then I want to read the CSV and output the event/s that match todays date. I also want to get tomorrows events as well.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above you do want to use `fgetcsv()`. Here's how you might do it (untested):

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   $today = strtotime("today");
   $tomorrow = strtotime("tomorrow");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (strtotime($data[0]) == $today || strtotime($data[0]) == $tomorrow)) {
            echo 'Category: ' . $data[1] . "<br>\n";
            echo 'Event: ' . $data[0] . "<br><br>\n\n";
        }        
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest (yet not optimal) way to do this is using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and then iterate over the table, picking out those dates that are today.

I'd probably reconsider the format of the data (make it a database), unless there are other apps depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty much many ways to read a CSV files; you can also read in line by line and use the split function to separate each filed as an element in an array.

If search speed and complexity is not a concern, you can do a linear iteration and check for dates. You may want to use strtotime to convert the date into a unix timestamp for comparison.

If the search speed is important, then convert the date to timestamp, have an associative array which key is the timestamp (essentially a hash table)

To get tomorrow's date, check out the [date function documentation in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
$today=date('d/m/Y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("Y"));
$tmr = date("d/m/Y", $tomorrow)."\n";
$handle = fopen("file", "r");
fgets($handle,2048);
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2048, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $date=explode("/",$data[0]);
    if ( $today == $data[0] || $tmr == $data[0]){
        $j = implode(",", $data);
        print $j."\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an *alternative* to `fgetcsv` and iterating, you could also use a Regular Expressions to get the appropriate lines, e.g. for

```
Date,Event,Description
24/01/2010,Football,Football practice for all Years.
24/01/2010,Cricket,Cricket Practice for all Years.
25/01/2010,Piano Lessons,Paino lessons for Year 10.
26/01/2010,Piano Lessons II.
```

use

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');    
$pattern = sprintf('#%s.*|%s.*#', date('d/m/Y'), 
                                  date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 day")) );
$file = file_get_contents('filename.csv');
preg_match_all($pattern, $file, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

and receive

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=> string(53) "24/01/2010,Football,Football practice for all Years."
    [1]=> string(51) "24/01/2010,Cricket,Cricket Practice for all Years."
    [2]=> string(52) "25/01/2010,Piano Lessons,Paino lessons for Year 10."
  }
}
```

Haven't benchmarked this though. Depending on the size of your CSV file, this could get memory intensive, due to `file_get_contents` loading the entire file into a variable.

---

Another *alternative* with [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/de/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php):

```
$today    = date('d/m/Y');
$tomorrow = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 day"));
$file = new SplFileObject("csvfile.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    list($date, $event, $description) = $row;
    if($date === $today || $date === $tomorrow) {
        echo "Come visit us at $date for $description";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spend lot of time trying to traverse each line in csv file, or can try something like that:

```
$command = sprintf("grep '%s' -Er %s", date('d/m/Y'), $this->db);
$result = `$command`;
```

This example really works and it is really fast!