# PHP/Shell - Fastest Way to Search a CSV with Wildcards for Matches

Tags: php, arrays, regex, grep, wildcard

i'm wondering what is the fastest way to search for matches in a csv with wildcards in PHP?

e.g. i have a simple text-file that looks this way (the % is the wildcard):

djfras, Hub3W, %k6q2, 88%hA, zzgsqw2, L632%%, ...

the function/regex/grep whatever should find matches for e.g.:

diFras or ok6q2 or L632s5

as this will happen several hundert times a second - what is the most robust, time and cpu saving method and how to implement?

thanx in advance

tom

edit: sorry i was too imprecise :) that happens while looping through the lines of a .json file with several hundred lines - the .json file itself is loaded fresh every second

Comment: Load the csv into a database first, add appropriate indexes, then search the database using SQL

Comment: Several hundred searches of a filesystem-based csv file per second is basically an impossibility

Comment: In regex, simply replace the `%` wildcard with proper regex wildcard - the dot `.`.

Comment: @mark baker - sorry i was too imprecise :) that happens while looping through the lines of a .json file with several hundred lines - the .json file itself is loaded fresh every second ...

Comment: Probably still better to have the upload dump it in a database, even if its a non-relational database like mongodb, and do your searches against that

Comment: @asunez i had a similar idea - but being very new to this 'regex-thing' i have no idea how to implement and moreover to implement it ressource-saving. should i use grep via php sprintf or php builtin regex function - and which and how :))) sorry ...

Comment: @mark baker - the problem is that it will run on a raspberry pi and the sd-cards aren't too happy about writing - and in addition i wanted to have the most compact solution and the number of items in the csv-list is not very big - say about up to 1000 search items ...

Comment: the problem is that php in_array function there is no way for wildcards - it finds just exact matches ... in_array($needle, $haystack_csv_array)

Comment: Take a look at a custom search function using [fnmatch()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) perhaps

Comment: Why not using SQLite? https://randomnerdtutorials.com/sqlite-database-on-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Also, there are PHP implementations of LINQ that might provide more efficient pseudo-SQL searching of arrays

Comment: @mark baker - thanx :) that was one of the builtin functions i thought it could help to get this done - but they say 'For now, this function is not available on non-POSIX compliant systems except Windows.' and i did wonder which are the non-posix-compliant systems they mention and are they relevant for users of my script? and moreover is fnmatch fast or is preg_match faster or should i use grep istead or is there a simple way to use one of the php-builtin string search functions (e.g. strstr, strpos) for this task as they seem to be very fast and resource-saving ...

Comment: @bato3 but what is the real advantage of using a database (for only about 1000 values) instead an array? beside to have the like operator - and is this really faster?

Comment: what i found yesterday was a post from user vladimir kovpac that looked promising - but i'm not able to adapt it to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41189488/8613418

Comment: @asunez and how would i then go further when i replaced the '%' with '.' e.g. like this way $new_user_array = str_replace('%', '.', $user_array)

Comment: or is the main advantage of vladimirs solution (in the other thread) just that he does not have to loop through all the rows using grep instead. and is grep used on just a single line of csv even not faster than the php built-in functions like preg_match or fnmatch???

Comment: @user8613418 what is faster: assembler or c#? The most important is the total processing time. And write application time. *It all depends* on how often you will be filtering. If data are semi-static, then you can use 2 data sources. Who is forbidding you? Question "Do I have to use a database here?" Is similar to: "Can I make a layout on tables?". Do you have a good reason to do it against the best models?

Comment: @user1194525 sorry - but i do not understand what the message is?

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i tinkered - seems to work - but in my eyes looks horrible stupid?

as i'm very new to this regex-thing - any idea/response/correction/improvement very welcome :)

and it seems to be about 10-20 times slower than the simple php built-in in_array search without wildcards. now i measured this - 30-50 times slower!!! puuuh

is there not a better/cleaner/faster way than my rookie-coding???

```
$haystack = explode(',', str_replace('%', '.', strtoupper('DEISD, B%W951%, CCA828')));

$needle = strtoupper('BAW951L');

foreach ($haystack as $pattern) {
    preg_match('/^' . trim($pattern) . '$/', $needle) ? $match = 'true' : $match = 'false';
    // just for debug print what it does
    print(preg_match('/' . trim($pattern) . '/', $needle) . PHP_EOL);
    print($match . PHP_EOL);
}
```